# My loop just exit itself

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, loops, user-interface

I need a solution from this lines of code i want to perform a 10 loops and at 10 i want it to system.exit(); where my GUI just exit itself, need help! currently this lines would just exit and it doesnt perform anything

```
int counter =  0;
            while(true){
                counter++;
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                if(counter < 10){
                    new Thread(new Person(bathroom, !isMale)).start();
                    new Thread(new Person(bathroom, isMale)).start();
                }
                else{
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
System.exit(0);
```

`System.exit` will exit *all* threads including the ones you've started.

You should wait for all threads to stop before exiting. Based on how they could be organized I'd count out the number of threads to be started and have them all wait on a countdown latch with the main thread at the end, or *much* simpler but more hackily, have the main thread include:

```
while(true){

}
```

at the end.

Comment: yes, Do i still need to have condition to stop it? I mean my condition only wants to exit if the counter 10 is met. I suppose if the counter is less than 10 the thread will start doesn't it? then if it's 10 it should do systemexit, what do you actually mean by countdown latch?

Comment: @ProblematicSolution I don't think you understand what the point of a thread is. A thread will run independently of other threads so when you start it it will run independently. The point here is that you need to learn threading concepts before trying to apply threading.

Answer (score 0):

after you have started the new threads , they will take their own course ..

you can use the join() function to ensure they finish running..